# "Tempura" setting on induction cooktops

Tags: deep-frying, induction

I was reading [this comment](https://www.chowhound.com/post/deep-fryer-856959?commentId=7440297) while once again wondering if I should get a deep fryer for the few occasions I would use it and I stumbled across "tempura" or "deep fry" modes on some induction cooktops.  At the time ~2012 one of the commenters indicated that these weren't available in the US.

Is this still true?  A quick internet search didn't turn any burners up that had these features but I'm not giving up the search.

Answer (score 1):

Most anything that can heat a pot or wok to 180-220°C CAN be used to deep fry, with the appropriate caution.

With all stovetop deep frying, use a thermometer, avoid straight-sided vessels like stockpots - boil-over events are a far greater and more dangerous mess if there is oil involved, do not leave things unattended, be prepared to deal with a fire, be VERY prepared to handle a boil-over, be careful adding water-rich things ESPECIALLY at low temperature.

The question is what such modes really do. They could enforce an upper limit to temperature - which I would consider unreliable unless there is a sensor IN the oil. The temperature range useful for deep frying is ~140-210°C, whereas upwards of 230°C things start to get dangerous.
Alternatively, they could just DISABLE a temperature limiter that would usually not even allow the pot to get as hot as it will get in deep frying (significantly above 100°C usually indicates the cooking vessel has boiled dry).
In either case, it is doubtful whether there is a safety benefit vs any other non-flame stovetop deep frying technique.

Comment: Oh I know it's possible.  From what I could deduce, however, the tempura setting allowed it to be used as a PID controller to regulate the temperature of the oil a bit better.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why avoid straight sides - does it make it more prone to roiling?